# How to find and convert strings that are using curly brackets {site_name} for example in a HTML textarea output?

Tags: php

I am designing a Mail Template editor in my application. I need an idea to find the occurance of specific variables to be able to convert them using preg_replace or preg_match in my code.

For example, my template looks like this: (Sample only) this is what is returned from the textarea variable.

```
<p>Thank you for your order at <a href="{site_url}" style="color:#ea6ea0">{site_name}</a>.</p>
```

In this example, I would like to replace the {site_url} with a specific variable or code from PHP since I can't parse PHP directly into the textarea.

Hope my question was clear, any help appreciated.

**Edit: Is my question clear? I need to replace the {} strings using my own php code. The php code cann't be used in textarea directly. That is why i need to find a templating system that replace predefined variables {... } but convert them using php when interpreting the template.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<p>Thank you for your order at <a href="<?=$site_url?>" style="color:#ea6ea0"><?=$site_name?></a>.</p>
```

or

```
<p>Thank you for your order at <a href="<?php echo $site_url?>" style="color:#ea6ea0"><?php echo $site_name?></a>.</p>
```

**edited:**

Ahhh, do you mean something like this then:

```
$html = '<p>Thank you for your order at <a href="{site_url}" style="color:#ea6ea0">{site_name}</a>.</p>';

$php_variables_array = array(
  "site_url" => "http://www.google.co.uk",
  "site_name" => "Google",
);

foreach ($php_variables_array as $key => $value)
{
  $html = str_replace("{" . $key . "}", $value, $html);
}

echo $html;
```

Comment: I want to convert the { ... } texts using php, i can't put variables directly in textarea and read them.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>" style="color:#ea6ea0"><?php echo $site_name;?></a>
```

Comment: I want to convert the  { ... } texts using php, i can't put variables directly in textarea and read them.